# Submit keeps refreshing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to create a quiz. I cant seem to figure out why every time I attempt to submit an answer the DOM is refreshing. I believe event.preventDefault() should be the solution but it's still not working. Is it an issue with the form?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Eagles Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wire.css"/>
</head>
<body class="flex-c">  
    <header class="flex-c">
        <section>
            <img class="city" src="img/philaskyline.jpg" alt="Philadelphia Skyline">
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Philadelphia Eagles Quiz</h1>
        </section>
    </header>
    <main class="flex-c">
        <section class="box">
            <h2>Prove You're the #1 Eagles Fan</h2>
            <section class="image">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Eagles Logo" class="container-img">
            </section>
            <section class="js-button">

                <button type="button" class="js-start">Start</button>

            </section>
        </section>
        <section class="js-progress">
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
      {
        question: "What was the Philadelphia Eagles first year in the NFL?",
        options: [
          "1933", 
          "1956", 
          "1941", 
          "1945"
        ],
        answer: "1933"
      },
      //2
      {
        question: "Who is the Eagles all time leading passer",
        options: [
          "Randall Cuningham",
          "Norm Van Brocklin", 
          "Donovan McNabb",
          "Ron Jaworski"
        ],
        answer: "Donovan McNabb"
      },
      //3
      {
        question: "Which Philadelphia Eagle was the first player in NFL history to record a sack, fumble recovery, TD, and an interception in the same game?",
        options: [
          "Reggie White", 
          "Andre Waters", 
          "Chuck Bednarik", 
          "Brian Dawkins"
        ],
        answer: "Brian Dawkins"
      },
      //4
      {
        question: "Nick Foles shares the NFL record for TD passes in a single game. What is the record", 
        options: [
            "8", 
            "7",
            "5",
            "4"
        ],
        answer: "7"
      },
      //5
      {
        question: "What is the name of the Eagles mascot?",
        options: [
          "Swoop", 
          "Baldy", 
          "Aquila", 
          "Franklin"
        ],
        answer: "Swoop"
      },
      //6
      {
        question: "What was the first Super Bowl appearance for the Eagles",
        options: [
          "Super Bowl XV", 
          "Super Bowl XI", 
          "Super Bowl XXXIX", 
          "Super Bowl XXIV"
        ],
        answer: "Super Bowl XV"
      },
      //7
      {
        question: "Who did the Eagles play in Super Bowl XXXIX",
        options: [
          "Indianapolis Colts", 
          "New England Patriots", 
          "Baltimore Ravens", 
          "Pittsburgh Steelers"
        ],
        answer: "New England Patriots"
      },
      //8
      {
        question: "Who was the first Eagles running back to toal more than 1,000 yard rushing in a season?", 
        options: [
          "Wilbert Montgomery", 
          "Lesean McCoy", 
          "Steve Van Buren", 
          "Brian Westbrook"
        ],
        answer: "Steve Van Buren"
      },
      //9
      {
        question: "Which former Eagle was the inspiration for the movie “Invincible”?",
        options: [
          "Jerome Brown", 
          "Sonny Jurgense", 
          "Tommy McDonald", 
          "Vince Papale"
        ], 
        answer: "Vince Papale"
      },
      //10
      {
        question: "Which Eagle was the last full-time two-way player in NFL history?",
        options: [
          "Pete Retzlaff", 
          "Pete Pihos", 
          "Al Wistert", 
          "Chuck Bednarik"
        ],
        answer: "Chuck Bednarik"
      }

    ];

const currentQuestionNumber= 0;
const score= 0;


//This function load quiz
function startQuiz(){
$('.start').on('click', function(event){
    renderQuestion();
    });
}

//This function renders question
function renderQuestion(){
    let questionText= STORE[currentQuestionNumber];
    let questionHtml= `<form><fieldset>
    <legend>${questionText.question}</legend>               
    <input type="radio" id="${questionText.options[0]}" value="${questionText.options[0]}"name="answer" required>
    <label for="${questionText.options[0]}">${questionText.options[0]}</label><br/>                       
    <input type="radio" id="${questionText.options[1]}" value="${questionText.options[1]}"name="answer" required>
    <label for="${questionText.options[1]}">${questionText.options[1]}</label><br/>       
    <input type="radio" id="${questionText.options[2]}" value="${questionText.options[2]}" name="answer" required>
    <label for="${questionText.options[2]}">${questionText.options[2]}</label></br>
    <input type="radio" id="${questionText.options[3]}" value="${questionText.options[3]}" name="answer" required>
    <label for="${questionText.options[3]}">${questionText.options[3]}</label><br>
    <button type="submit" class="js-button">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>`;
   $('.box').html(questionHtml);   
}

//this function check answer
function checkAnswer(){
    $('main').on('submit', '.submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let selected= $('input:checked')
    let answer= selected.val();
    let correct= STORE[currentQuestionNumber].answer;
    if (answer===correct){
        correctAnswer();
    } else {
        wrongAnswer();
    }
    });
}

//displays html when answer is correct
function correctAnswer(){
    const correct= `<h2>It's Good!</h2>
    <section class="image">
        <img src="img/td.jpg" alt="referee signaling touchdown" class="container-img">
    </section>
    <section class="js-button">
        <button type="button" class="js-next">Next</button>
    </section>`
    $('.box').html(correct);
    score++;
}
//displays html when answer is wrong
function wrongAnswer(){
    const wrong= `<h2>No good!</h2>
    <section class="image">
        <img src="img/missed.jpg" alt="david akers on knees after missing field goal" class="container-img">
    </section>
    <section class="js-button">
        <button type="button" class="js-next">Next</button>
    </section>`
    $('.box').html(wrong);
}




function domReady(){
    startQuiz();
    checkAnswer();
    nextQuestion();
    renderQuestion();
    wrongAnswer();
    correctAnswer();

};


$(domReady);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Is it an issue with the form` - yes, submitting a form loads a new page (or the same page if no action is set on the form element) -  I see you try to intercept the submit action using `$('main').on('submit', '.submit',` with a `preventDefault` however, you fail here, as you have no element with class `submit`

Comment: I'm still getting the same refresh issue when updated to this 

<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>

Comment: Change all instances of `<button type="submit" class="js-button">Submit</button>` to `<button type="button" class="js-button">Submit</button>` and catch the `on('submit'` as `on('click;'` instead. Read more on the types of buttons here: [Submit, Button, Reset](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

Comment: because it's the FORM that submits, not the button

Comment: @CarloG1118 You also have to fix problem with using same `class` names for `buttons` and `sections` in `Next` : `<section class="js-button">
        <button type="button" class="js-next">Next</button>
    </section>`

Comment: @Bravo That was my issue. I updated the form to <form class="js-question"> then used $('main').on('submit', '.js-question', 

appreciate everyones help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
function startQuiz(){
   $('.js-start').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      renderQuestion();
      return false;
   });
}
...
function checkAnswer(){
    $('.box').on('submit', '.js-button', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       let selected= $('input:checked');
       let answer= selected.val();
       let correct= STORE[currentQuestionNumber].answer;
       if (answer===correct){
           correctAnswer();
       } else {
           wrongAnswer();
       }
       return false;
    });
}
```